# AspNetCore project gives System.IO.FileNotFoundException only on linux container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've got a dotnet core project running AspNetCore webserver. I use a couple of other DLLs which is are fairly simple class libaries.

I can download the repository from git onto my windows PC, go in and run:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

And everything works fine.

However if I do the same thing in a docker container based on microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.7, I get the following error on an HTTP PUT:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLBKHRVH7OND": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'KolData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Now the file Koldata.dll does exist in the git repository and it's there in the bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1 folder.

I can re-create the error in Windows by deleting the KolData.dll file in the build directory. So it seems to be that dotnet core on Linux cannot see that file, and I'm unsure why.

I've even tried replacing the DLL with a version built on the machine from source, and it still brings the same error.

**One solution**

I managed to get it working by changing the csproj file's target framework from:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This feels a bit strange since KolData.dll is running on 1.1
But now it runs without the error.

Comment: `KolData` doesn't look like a *package* name. Did you forget to publish one of your DLLs *in the container*? Unless you created the container to *build* the project, it shouldn't contain any repositories or build directories

Comment: As I said. The Koldata.dll is in the repository, and it is in the project and it is in the build directory. So the file is where it should be, but dotnet core is not seeing it, or loading it.

Comment: You say the file is in the repository and outputs to the build directory but have you confirmed the package is inside the docker image?  How are you building the docker image?

Comment: I'm just using the microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.7 image to create a container and then I'm using exec to open a bash to it. Then I'm just writing commands like 'git clone <etc>'  then cd <etc> and dotnet restore and so on.

Comment: @DaveAlger that image is meant for *building*, not *deployment*. That's why saying "it's in the repository" sounds so strange. Unless you *build* your project inside that image you can't assume that it can be built or run. For example placing anything in the *bin/Debug* folder of an application guarantees it will be deleted when `dotnet run` runs the build step. Building starts by *deleting* the files in the output directory, ie `bin/Debug`

Comment: @DaveAlger if you want to *publish* your application, use [microsft/aspnetcore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/). It's a *lot* smaller because it doesn't include the files used for building, ie th .NET Core SDK, Grunt, Bower and Gulp

Comment: I'll look at options for publishing things when things are working. 

Just to re-iterate I run "dotnet restore" & "dotnet run" in the image. So I'm building the project and the required dll (which is present in the repository) is copied appropriately by the build into the bin/Debug directory. Yet it's still "FileNotFound"-

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2017 there is a built-in support for Docker.

Comment: Can you please provide your docker file code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Dockerfile and build docker image.

EDIT:
An example of what Dockerfile should look like. The following file builds Visual Studio project and creates docker image.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj WebApplication/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]
```

If you have already built your application include .dll in container with Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "application.dll"]
```

Build and run your app:

```
docker build -t application
docker run -d -p 8000:80 application
```

[Building Docker Images for .NET Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/building-net-docker-images)

Comment: All this does is create an image with my application built in it. (Which is what I had done through the manual process of building from bash).

I then run the container from this image, issue a push to the webserver and get EXACTLY THE SAME ERROR.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "issue a push to the webserver". If you are referencing any library or project in your application you must include it in Dockerfile and build it along with your application.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Put. Http Put.

Comment: I assume KolData.dll is library you are referencing to from other project. You either don't have KolData.dll in a container or path is not correct. When creating container with multiple projects you have to include all projects (.dll files) that are being referenced from main application.

Comment: As I said from the very beginning "it's there in the bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1 folder." - where it should be. 
I've managed to get it working by downgrading the project to netcoreapp1.0 (while the Koldata.dll still runs 1.1). Seems an odd situation to me.